# Chat Component for my APP built on React Native EXPO Framework

Tags: react-native, expo, chat

I m building a new app using `React Native EXPO` framework. My app requires a chat function where users can chat within the app. Simple one-on-one chat with typing indicator, read receipts, online/offline status and image transfer are the features I would like to provide my users with.

Please let me know of any free or paid service that will work with `React Native EXPO framework`. I have seen many options online for `Core React Native` but none for `EXPO`.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I use [stream-chat-expo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-chat-expo) on my Expo projects. Stream's Messaging API allows you to build real-time chat applications verry fast. Here the [tutorial for Stream chat(with Expo)](https://getstream.io/blog/add-in-app-messaging-to-your-mobile-app-react-native-expo/)

You can also try [react-native-gifted-chat](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat)